# How to tell an ECT developed in VS to use credentials from Secure Store Service?

Tags: visual-studio, bcs, external-content-type, secure-store

I am trying to develop an External Content Type using Visual Studio so I can use External Data Source columns in a SharePoint list.

Most of the stuff I am finding online uses Designer, but I don't want to use designer, I want to use VS so I have a `.wsp` I can deploy to different environments.  Note also, I do *not* want to create an External List, I want a hybrid, so I just want the ECT available to be able to use external data columns on a regular SharePoint list.

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2009/12/03/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-external-content-type-with-crud-methods-using-linq-and-a-sql-lob-system/) to create the ECT definition, and I can deploy it and it shows up in the BCS service app, and I can see it when I add columns to a list.

I have also been following the instructions [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219584.aspx), and more specifically [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683109.aspx), to set up credentials in the Secure Store Service that are valid on the external data source (a SQL DB, in this case).

What I can't seem to find, though, is where in my VS project I tell the ECT to use credentials from the Secure Store Service when trying to connect to the external data?

I found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556780(v=office.14).aspx), but again, that uses Designer, and I don't want to do it in Designer.

So, **where in my Visual Studio project do I go to tell the ECT to look for credentials in the Secure Store Service?**

Or is it not in the VS project?  Is there some setting on the ECT I set through the BCS service app in Central Admin?